# Adding salt to Blake3 Key derive function

Tags: key-derivation, salt, blake3

According to the whitepaper, `Blake3` can be used as a key derivation function (function `key_derive`). Currently, as a key derivation function, I used Rust's `Hkdf::<Sha256>` which takes as input the `master key` and `salt`. Adding `salt` allows to ensure that even in the case I reuse the `master key`, the output of the `Hkdf` is randomized and cannot be linked to previous derivations.

Since Blake3 is much faster than Sha256 I would like to use it as my KDF, however, according to the [whitepaper](https://github.com/BLAKE3-team/BLAKE3-specs/blob/master/blake3.pdf) Blake3 takes only a `key material` and `context string`, which should be `" hardcoded, globally unique and application-specific (...) should not contain variable data like salts, IDs or current time".`

How can I then add salt to `Blake3` key derivation function, to ensure that even if I reuse the same master key multiple times, the output of the key derivation is randomized?

Comment: prefix to your key?

Comment: @kelalaka I thought about that, but is it secure? If I feed into Blake3 salt || master key, won't the output be partially similar to the output of Blake3 for just master key as input?

Comment: Why it should be? If so, then any MD-based hash function will be totally insecure. Also, Blake2,3 are immune to length extension attacks.

Comment: @kelalaka Great, thanks a lot!